# Specifying step definition path in Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, protractor, webstorm, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am currently using Protractor and Cucumber.js to run automation tests on an Angular app. I use Webstorm and two plugins, Cucumber.js and Gherkin.

The problem I am having is when trying to specify a unique location for the step definitions directory. Sense I have multiple projects that use some of the same step definitions, I want to be able to eliminate duplicate code and pull those step definitions into a common/shared directory.

I was able to get my code working, but the Gherkin/Cucumber.js plugins do not recognize where the step definitions are. This takes away a lot of useful highlighting and file locating tools. So, has anyone ran into this problem, or does anyone know how I can specify a custom step definitions location?

Answer (score 1):

you won't be able to do much for WebStorm to recognize your steps. Create a symlink instead.

Two options:

## 1 create reference to your private module

1. create a private module with your step definitions
2. in step_definitions folder create a file 'whatever.js'
3. in that file type: module.exports = require('myPrivateModule');

## 2 create a symlink from your private module to your step_definitions folder

I prefer the second option because WebStorm is able to recognize steps that way and remove unknown step definition highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following directory structure:

```
test/componentA/first.feature
test/componentA/step_definitions/firstFeaturesSteps.js
test/componentB/second.feature
test/componentB/step_definitions/secondFeaturesSteps.js
test/step_definitions/someCommonSteps.js
```

The Tests should match successfully if the protractor.conf.js (or wtv you named it) has

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/**/step_definitions/**/*Steps.js'],
    format: 'pretty'
}
```

If you're using WebStorm or IDEA then the auto-complete and ctrl-click magic will work if you drop your step definitions in a 'step_definitions' directory. You should be able to ctrl-click on your .feature's steps to get to the step definition...even if the step in first.feature matches a step definition in commonSteps.js or secondFeaturesSteps.js. The IDE seems to know where the Steps are only if they're in step_definition directories and it is unrelated to the source files passed in cucumberOpts.require.